# Есть ли у этих глаголов пары несоверш. вида?

Tags: глаголы, морфология

В книге Розенталя написано, что для глаголов совершенного вида *жениться*, *закричать*, *разбудить*, *посидеть* нет парных глаголов несовершенного вида. А разве это не пары: *закричать* -- *кричать*, *разбудить* -- *будить*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> жениться

Двухвидовой глагол. Сам себе пара.

> закричать, разбудить, посидеть

Тут есть некоторая неднозначность в термине "парный".    
Стопроцентными "парами" к приставочным глаколам совершенного вида можно считать только вторично имперфективировнные глаголы типа *выловить-вылавливать, прибить-прибивать, нажать - нажимать, задержать-задерживать, окупить-окупать*. Именно об  этом, видимо, и идет речь в вашем источнике.

Что же касается пары к бесприставочным глаголам совершенного вида, то только единицы имеет стопроцентные пары (решить-решать, брать-взять). Для всех остальных обычно подбирают пару из числа приставочных. Но при этом надо иметь в виду, что наличие приставки может само по себе вносить дополнительную семантику.
Так, в вашем случае *закричать* означает не просто совершенный вид к *кричать*, но наличие обозримого момента начала этого действия. Фразу *они кричали* невозможно сказать в совершенном виде, не внеся дополнительного оттенка. *Разбудить* - не просто совершенный вид к *будить* - это еще и достижение результата. Могли ведь будить - и недобудиться...
Вот насчет *посидеть* - тут, пожалуй, *сидеть* почти точная пара (приставка "по" очень часто вносит наименьшее уточнение в семантику и потому часто образует такую "приблизительную" пару). Но тоже не совсем, ведь *посидеть* - это не просто совершить процесс сидения, это еще и посидеть немного, недолго, неудобно и проч.

Другое дело, что "абсолютных" пар обычно не имеют как раз те приставочные глаголы, которые наиболее близки по семантике своим бесприставочным парам. Тоже, кстати, объяснимо, язык не терпит излишеств. Но это уже отдельный разговор.

Answer (score 2):

Закричать - кричать - согласна, не пара.

Видовая пара - это пара лексически тождественных глаголов сов. и несов. вида, различающихся между собой только грамматической семантикой вида: делать - сделать, переписать - переписывать.

В глаголе закричать префикс вносит значение начала действия; семантического тождества с мотивирующим глаголом кричать нет, видовая пара не создается. Способом суффиксации несов. вид от глагола закричать также не образуется. Гл. закричать остается несоотносительным глаголом сов. вида.

Кричать - крикнуть - тоже не пара, потому что  крикнуть - это однократное действие, само по себе предельное, непредельным быть не может.

Разбудить - будить - на мой взгляд, пара.

Здесь префикс раз - вносит значение "доводить - довести действие до результата": будить - разбудить, как и  бередить - разбередить; делить - разделить, фасовать - расфасовать, пороть - распороть, молоть - размолоть, жевать - разжевать (что-либо). Это соотносительные по виду глаголы.

А в какой кгиге у Розенталя так написано? Ссылочку не дадите? Может, там речь о чём-то другом?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрим в словари:

У слова "кричать" (издавать крик) несколько значений, но парный глагол СВ не указан. Дело в том, что закричать (в основном значении) - это начать кричать.

А вот глагол "будить" имеет два парных глагола СВ: будить - разбудить (заставить встать) и будить - пробудить (вызвать чувства, пробудить любовь).

ЖЕНИТЬСЯ - двувидовой глагол (СВ и НСВ).